# Setting position of decimal point in exponential number format

Tags: decimal-number

How can I change the number of digits displayed before the decimal point when displaying a number in scientific format?
In the code below, I'd like to get something like **13.9e9** displayed in the x-axis instead of **1.39e10**.
[image]

Thanks for your answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=3}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=13900000000,
xmax=14100000000,
xlabel={$f$ [Hz]},
ylabel={$|E_{T12}(f)|$},
]
\addplot [color=black]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
13900000256 0.772152900695801\\
13939000320 0.768190622329712\\
13978999744 0.772846043109894\\
14003000320 0.777175188064575\\
14033000448 0.773870348930359\\
14062000128 0.767529368400574\\
14078999552 0.768778383731842\\
14099999744 0.771605312824249\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could add `scaled ticks=base 10:-9` to the `axis` options.

Comment: Thanks, this works for the x-axis, but makes the numbers at the y-axis unreadable. How can I apply this option just for the numbers at the x-axis?

Comment: `scaled x ticks=base 10:-9` should only apply the changes to the x axis. Sorry for overlooking that in my initial comment.

Comment: Oh thanks, that works perfectly